# Java JNA 4.3.0 Creates Insane Amout of Garbage When Looking for Process

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jna, garbage

JNA is making an insane amount of garbage when I'm trying to find a fake process by name.

Here is a screenshot of the allocations (about 100k.sec)

[image]

Here is the test case (used 4.3.0 SNAPSHOT of JNA)

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Tlhelp32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT;

/**
 * Created by Jonathan on 8/26/2016.
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true)
            openProcess("doesntexist.exe");
    }

    private static final WinDef.DWORD DWORD_ZERO = new WinDef.DWORD(0);
    private static final Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32 entry = new Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32.ByReference();

    private static WinNT.HANDLE openProcess(String processName) {
        WinNT.HANDLE snapshot = Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(Tlhelp32.TH32CS_SNAPALL, DWORD_ZERO);
        try {
            while (Kernel32.INSTANCE.Process32Next(snapshot, entry)) {
                String fileName = Native.toString(entry.szExeFile);
                if (processName.equals(fileName))
                    return Kernel32.INSTANCE.OpenProcess(WinNT.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, true, entry.th32ProcessID.intValue());
            }
        } finally {
            Kernel32.INSTANCE.CloseHandle(snapshot);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

And finally here is the memory snapshot
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91292881/ShareX/2016/08/JNA%204.3.0.snapshot

Comment: How many processes are you creating?  Just tracing the code it looks like the while loop creates a `Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32` structure for every one of them.

Comment: Also where are you getting 4.3.0?  The latest release is 4.2.2.  Is this a snapshot build?

Comment: Yes this is a snapshot build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect your heap usage is the repeated creation of new `String` objects inside your loop.

Your code executes the process search (which looks through every process) inside another endless loop so you're effectively executing this line over and over...

```
String fileName = Native.toString(entry.szExeFile);
```

Internally, `Native.toString(char[] buf)` is creating a `new String()` each time:

```
public static String toString(char[] buf) {
    int len = buf.length;
    for (int index = 0; index < len; index++) {
        if (buf[index] == '\0') {
            len = index;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (len == 0) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return new String(buf, 0, len);
    }
}
```

These `String` objects are used once to test equality and then are tossed on to the heap.

Since the main purpose of creating the `String` is to test equality, you can probably test equality directly using the underlying `char[]` array.  Convert `processName` to a `char[]` and iterate simultaneously over both arrays, testing for character equality up to the length of `processName` with a null terminator in the next character of `entry.szExeFile`.